# Payment Shared (mjwshared) - Table 'civicrm_paymentprocessor_webhook' doesn't exist

Tags: upgrade, database, payment-processor

Apologies if answered elsewhere/already (point me in the right direction please as I've not found it yet!).

I inherited a Civi+WP installation which seems to be missing this table:

```
civicrm_paymentprocessor_webhook
```

- Civi core 5.44
- Payment Shared (mjwshared) 1.0.1

During the course of updating Civi core and extensions to their latest versions I discovered this problem - which blocks updating both this extension and Stripe.

I looked at the release notes and it sounded as though it might have been introduced in 1.1 (I realised subsequently that it isn't), so I started again with a clean db and "baby steps", upgrading 1.0.1 > 1.1 - with same results.

I then checked the production site and saw the same error in the logs there too. Aha! A pre-existing condition. Also filling the logs with huge db output, dumped each time the issue is provoked.

So... how can I get this table? When was it introduced? What is the best way forward? (as an aside: How can it *not* be present in the first place??!).

I have root access to the dev server and db, and cli tools such as cv and could write a CREATE for the table, but would like to do things the "right" way and avoid introducing any other/new problems.

Any thoughts/suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below sql and check if it works

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_paymentprocessor_webhook` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique PaymentprocessorWebhook ID',
  `payment_processor_id` int unsigned COMMENT 'Payment Processor for this webhook',
  `event_id` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Webhook event ID',
  `trigger` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Webhook trigger event type',
  `created_date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'When the webhook was first received by the IPN code',
  `processed_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Has this webhook been processed yet?',
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT "new" COMMENT 'Processing status',
  `identifier` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Optional key to group webhooks, as needed by some processors.',
  `message` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT "" COMMENT 'Stores data sent that is needed for processing. JSON suggested.',
  `data` text COMMENT 'Stores data sent that is needed for processing. JSON suggested.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `index_event_id`(event_id),
  INDEX `index_created_date`(created_date),
  INDEX `index_processed_date`(processed_date),
  INDEX `index_status_processed_date`(status, processed_date),
  INDEX `index_identifier`(identifier),
  CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_paymentprocessor_webhook_payment_processor_id FOREIGN KEY (`payment_processor_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_payment_processor`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used the CREATE statement and it was possible to proceed through updating the extensions. CV did inform of an issue with subsequent table alter (of that table)  during the update, but the db upgrade went through. I will follow up on that (alter), but your response addresses the primary blocking issue/query of "how can I get this table" so I mark as answered. Much appreciated.